# SSL certificates, cookies/cache, can’t view my own website…

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, security-certificate, accessibility, connections

### Can’t access my own site without occasional error message

> **“can’t establish a secure connection”.**

So I ran a **Windows diagnostic**, which yielded zero results.

So I **deleted my cookies and my cache** (as per the site’s admin recommendations). I even **deleted all my browsing history**.

So I got it to ***temporarily*** work for me.

Then I started experiencing the same problem.

Of course I contacted Customer Service again, and they mentioned that the usage of a **subdomain** may be what is creating this error message and inability to access it. They recommended ***buying an SSL Certificate and a domain.***

They also recommended *not* using my Wi-Fi. So I used my mobile data… and again, the problem was resolved. Or kind of resolved…

## Dilemma

I’m still unable to use my desktop (hotspot is too slow) to finish designing my commerce site, to finish adding all the details and images of my product listings unless I stay in the editing mode.. but the editor doesn’t actually allow me to click on the links on my website to test how they function, or if they function in a buyers point of view. It only allows me to edit search content. During the creation of my site, I sincerely don’t want to pay for the additional expenses, but I also want to be able to see the progress and any potential problems with the site as I’m creating it.

## My Plan

Anyways, my plan is to finish creating ny commerce website completely, and then go pay for a domain versus using a subdomain.

> But will this really resolve my problems or am I going to spend days/
> weeks/ months on this to find out the hard way that there is some
> other problem? Such as the usage of the hosting site??

### Additional background

#### (I don’t know how relevant this is but since this is all new to me, I just thought I would share some additional details if it helps anyone help me):

1. I have spectrum Internet. Is there a way that I can get my Wi-Fi to stop blocking my own website?
2. I’m using a platform called freewebstore.
3. Is it possible that not having all of my product images is creating this problem for me?
4. Is it possible that not having anything more on my product listings filled in other than the title, the price, the check out form, or the shipping price, and the category is what is creating my site to be blocked for marked as “unsecured”?

#### Temporarily Missing Data

To be more specific other aspects of the product listing that are missing on most of these products include the :

shipping weight
Shipping dimensions
Product weight
Product dimensions
Brand-name (even though it’s always included in my title)
MPN
UPC
Product images

#### Included Data

Things I already have included are the following:

1. Terms of use
2. Return policy
3. Contact phone number
4. Contact email
5. An about me that describes the kind of items I sell, where I’m located, etc.
6. the title for product listings
7. The description box has the title copied and pasted
8. the price,
9. the check out form,
10. The shipping price
11. the category of the product
12. Contact form to write a message to me directly with questions when someone doesn’t want to copy and paste my email or call my phone number.
13. Privacy Policy
14. A logo
15. More than 1,000 incomplete product listings. (And thousands left to go…)

> (I’m not trying to post this article to self promote
> or anything like that so that’s why I haven’t included the link to my site…
> if that helps anybody I’ll post it upon request…)

Any/all help is appreciated truly.

## Questions

#### Just to recap, here is my list of questions:

```
1.  Why am I experiencing this error message? (Can’t establish secure connection)
2.  Is the usage of freewebstore as the host causing this problem?
3.  Will my problem go away once I pay for a domain? (Keep in mind that freewebstore’s TOS states that I already have a free ssl so I’m confused about why they are still telling me to get one)
4.  Is buying an SSL certificate separate from buying a domain?
5.  Does the accessibility of my website have anything to do with the fact that it’s not SEO friendly yet?
6.  Do the temporary lack of images on my product listings create this issue?
7.  Do you need my link to my site to answer these questions?
8.  Is there a way to get Spectrum to stop blocking my website? Like on the My Spectrum app or on spectrum’s website whenever i login? 
9.  Is it ridiculous to call Spectrum and ask them What’s up? Loll
```

Thanks!

Annie

Comment: 1. It could be due to your browser, device, or internet connection. You've tried a different connection (cellular data) and it seemed to fix the issue, so I would try a different browser/device. If this is an issue with your browser/device, then we can stop worrying about the website itself. 2. Possible. Again I would try a different browser and/or device to help determine whether it's a device issue or host issue. 3. No. At best their CS is completely clueless on that front; at worst they are intentionally using the flakiness of their server to try to upsell you on something you do not need.

Comment: 4. Yes. But SSL certificates are generally free nowadays - if they try to charge you for one, just realize it's likely a 100% profit upsell for them. 5. No. The secure connection error has nothing to do with the content of the website. 6. No, for the same reason. 7. We don't review individual websites on this forum, so we appreciate that you've made your question self-contained with no links to the site needed. 8-9. I don't believe this is a Spectrum issue unless you're running into problems accessing websites other than just your own.

Comment: As a final piece of advice, try ruling out time-related issues. If you published your web store recently, give it a few hours and try again, as there might be some DNS process at your host that hasn't quite settled in yet. And double check to make sure the time and date on your device are accurately set - that can cause a lot of browser issues relating to secure connections!